# How to get the 10-logarithm of an Integer?

Tags: ada

I want to ask the user to write in an Integer(N) and then I display the 10-logarithm of the Integer he/she entered. I have successfully calculated the 10-logarithm but do not know how to display it like the following ex:

```
Write in an Integer: 455666
455666 / 10 = 45566
45566 / 10 = 4556
4556 / 10 = 455
455 / 10 = 45
45 / 10 = 4
Answer: 10-logarithm of 455666 is 5.
```

Here is my code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;                    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;            use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;              use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure Logarithm is
  X: Integer;
begin
  Put("Write in an Integer: ");
  Get(X);
  for I in 1..X loop
    if 10**I<=X then
      Put(I);
    end if;
  end loop;
end Logarithm;
```

Comment: Your example shows how to calculate the integer logarithm but your code does not implement the algorithm shown in the example.
For some reason you output a number if its square is less than the value you want to compute the logarithm of. Nowhere do you actually calculate the integer logarithm.

How does your program the logarithm base 10 rather than, say, base 2?

Comment: [sliderule](https://web.mit.edu/2.972/www/reports/slide_rule/slide_rule.html)

Comment: The output example at the top of your question shows a series of successive divisions. You must perform those divisions to provide the equivalent output.

Answer (score 2):

The following program will calculate the integer logarithm of any value satisfying the Ada subtype `Positive` to any `Positive` base.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Integer_Logarithm is
   subtype Base_Range is Integer range 2..Integer'Last;
   Count : Natural := 0;
   Base  : Base_Range;
   Num   : Positive;
   Inpt  : Positive;
begin
   Put ("Enter the integer logarithmic base: ");
   Get (Base);
   Put ("Enter the integer: ");
   Get (Inpt);
   Num := Inpt;
   while Num >= Base loop
      Put (Num'Image & " /" & Base'Image & " =");
      Num := Num / Base;
      Put_Line (Num'Image);
      Count := Count + 1;
   end loop;
   Put_Line
     ("The integer logarithm (base" & Base'image & ") of" & Inpt'Image &
      " is" & Count'Image);
end Integer_Logarithm;
```

When executed using the example above the resulting output is:

```
Enter the integer logarithmic base: 10
Enter the integer: 455666
 455666 / 10 = 45566
 45566 / 10 = 4556
 4556 / 10 = 455
 455 / 10 = 45
 45 / 10 = 4
The integer logarithm (base 10) of 455666 is 5
```

When executed for base 2 and a value of 256 the result is

```
Enter the integer logarithmic base: 2
Enter the integer: 256
 256 / 2 = 128
 128 / 2 = 64
 64 / 2 = 32
 32 / 2 = 16
 16 / 2 = 8
 8 / 2 = 4
 4 / 2 = 2
 2 / 2 = 1
The integer logarithm (base 2) of 256 is 8
```

Comment: I note that a Base of 1 is allowed, and results in Count overflowing.

Comment: You are correct. One can simply declare Base to be an instance of a subtype declared as subtype Base_Range is Integer range 2..Integer'Last